# Parsing php date and time in jquery datepicker

Tags: php, jquery

I have a dateTime stored in my db as

```
2014-10-29 19:44:22
```

I am trying to set min date of DatePicker

Here is the code in php.

```
$creationDate =  $record['creationDate'];
                    $timestamp = strtotime($creationDate);
                    $year  =  date("y", $timestamp);
                    $month =  date("m", $timestamp);
                    $day   =  date("d", $timestamp);
```

Later in jquery

```
 $( "#calendar" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(<?php echo $year . "," .$month . "," .$day  . ",1"?>)});
```

result not working
any fix?

Comment: What's the format in datepicker?

Comment: * @syntax new Date() new Date(milliseconds) new Date(dateString) new Date(year, month, day [, hour, minute, second, millisecond ])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
     $("#calendar").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            minDate: '<?php echo date("Y-m-d",strtotime($creationDate)); ?>',
        });
```

change both format `dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',` and `date('Y-m-d')` according to your need.

For example if datepicker showing :- 2020/03/26 then

```
dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd',
minDate: '<?php echo date("Y/m/d",strtotime($creationDate)); ?>',
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try.

```
$( "#calendar" ).datepicker({
     minDate: new Date(<?php
         echo date('Y, m, d',strtotime($yourDateVar));
     ?>)
});
```